# how to hide a column of gridview when I add data in rutnime?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I do this to add data to a gridview

```
Dim dSource As New SqlDataSource
dSource.ConnectionString = MyConnectionString
dSource.SelectCommand = "select..."

GridView1.DataSource = dSource
GridView1.DataBind()
```

and then I want to hide the first column

```
GridView1.columns(0).visible=false
```

and the server throws an Exception:

```
ArgumentOutOfRangeException.
```

Comment: Where do you pu this in you code GridView1.columns(0).visible=true ?

Comment: Where do you do databind(), in which event?

Comment: `GridView1.columns[0].visible=false` you should put square brackets.

Comment: I do it in Page_Load() event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GridView.Columns.Count` will be 0 when you set `AutoGenerateColumns="true"` in your GridView.

You could try explicitly declaring your columns and setting `AutoGenerateColumns="false"`, or you could try using this in your codebehind:

`GridView.Rows[0].Cells.Count`

to get the column count once the data has been bound, or this:

```
protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Cells[index].Visible = false;
}
```

to set a column invisible using the GridView's RowDataBound event.

### Edit 1

You can use `bound field` as follow

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="DefaultGrid" Runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns=False>
     <Columns>
          <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Index"  HeaderText="Header">
          </asp:BoundColumn>
     </Columns>
 </asp:DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks. and how can i add columns to the gridview?

Answer (score 0):

You can hide grid view columns after databind
by using this code

```
protected void gridView_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{

    if (someCondition == true)
    {
        // Hide the column
        this.gridView.Columns[0].Visible = false;
    }
}
```